# Is there a concept of imprisonment in Jewish law?

Tags: halacha-theory, beit-din-court

Outside of a case I can't exactly recall (where Reuvein hurts Shimon and we don't know if Shimon will survive, Reuvein is held in like a prison until he gets better or dies), it seems that Jewish punishment is mainly *k'naas*, *misah*, or *malkus*.

Why do you think there's no concept of prison like there is in other societies?

Comment: also an Ir Miklat

Comment: Though this could have been closed as opinion based. Don't ask what we think. We're just fools with internet connections.

Comment: @rosends ah good call (although that sounds cushy for a prison) thanks for the heads up- will try to refrain from opinion based q's in the future

Comment: It's advised to formulate a question in an open form "is there" vs "why there's no" as you might be surprised by the answers.

Comment: @DoubleAA Interestingly, this Title is far better, as the other question totally misses הבור of Yossef as the ultimate Egyptian prison - so it IS explicitly mentioned in the Torah. However all the answers there follow this title.